# What is wrong with this simple Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am in the process of moving from Juno to Luna. I have developed a plugin that was working in Juno but I am having trouble getting it set up in Luna.

So, in order to figure out what is going wrong I created a simple empty plugin and ran it. The new instance of Eclipse does open but several exceptions are thrown (see below).

I don't know if this has anything to do with why my old plugin is not working but I thought I would start here. Any ideas why and empty plugin would behave like this?

```
    !SESSION 2015-03-26 13:20:14.478 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data /Users/markm208/Desktop/experimental_storyteller/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:/Users/markm208/Desktop/experimental_storyteller/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.core 4 0 2015-03-26 13:20:19.438
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.fx.core [343]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
       org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [352]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util 4 0 2015-03-26 13:20:19.485
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util [345]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="0.9.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.201408150602"
       org.eclipse.fx.core [343]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
              org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [352]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser 4 0 2015-03-26 13:20:35.819
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser [856]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util; bundle-version="0.9.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util; bundle-version="1.0.0.201408150602"
       org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util [345]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="0.9.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.201408150602"
              org.eclipse.fx.core [343]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
                     org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [352]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted 4 0 2015-03-26 13:20:35.828
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted [863]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser; bundle-version="3.6.2.201410090827-RELEASE"; singleton:="true"
       org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser [856]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util; bundle-version="0.9.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util; bundle-version="1.0.0.201408150602"
              org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util [345]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.201408150602"
                     org.eclipse.fx.core [343]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
                            org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [352]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY plugin2 4 0 2015-03-26 13:20:35.834
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: plugin2 [879]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="1.0.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.fx.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.201408150602"
       org.eclipse.fx.core [343]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.0.v20140415-1436"
              org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [352]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-03-26 13:20:47.510
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 4 0 2015-03-26 13:20:51.810
!MESSAGE Unexpected error while loading repository template extensions
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 4 0 2015-03-26 13:20:51.811
!MESSAGE Could not load repository template extension contributed by 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui' with connectorKind 'jira'
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 4 0 2015-03-26 13:20:51.811
!MESSAGE Could not load repository template extension contributed by 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui' with connectorKind 'jira'

!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui 4 0 2015-03-26 13:21:09.212
!MESSAGE Unexpected exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Unable to open editor, unknown editor ID: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard'
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$23(WorkbenchPage.java:3125)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$9.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3066)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3047)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui.actions.ShowDashboardPageAction$1.runInUIThread(ShowDashboardPageAction.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3983)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-03-26 13:21:09.213
!MESSAGE Unable to open editor, unknown editor ID: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard'
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
13:21:21.950 [Worker-6] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob - Queued refresh request: [/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/pom.xml, /TT/pom.xml]
13:21:23.218 [Worker-5] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.ProjectRegistryManager - Refreshing: [L/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/pom.xml, L/TT/pom.xml]
13:21:23.250 [Worker-5] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.ProjectRegistryManager - Refreshed: [L/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/pom.xml, L/TT/pom.xml]
```

Comment: The plugin requires Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e(fx)clipse tooling requires Java 1.8, so make sure your rutime Execution Environment is set to 1.8. There is supposed to be some "helper" plugin that alerts you to this (see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/987035/) but maybe you don't have that bundle included in your runtime configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue so just I have changed JDK 6 to JDK 7 using environment variable in my computer session and now it is working fine.